# proof, for a differentiable function from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}$, $\int_{Cpq}{\nabla f\cdot\mathrm{d}\boldsymbol{r}} = f(q)-f(p)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, geometry

For a differentiable function:
$f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$

prove that:

$$\int_{C_{\boldsymbol{pq}}}{\nabla f}\cdot\mathrm{d}\boldsymbol{r}=f(\boldsymbol{q})-f(\boldsymbol{p})$$

where $C$ is any differentiable path from $\boldsymbol{p}$ to $\boldsymbol{q}$

Then:
What can you say about $\oint_C{\nabla f\cdot\mathrm{d}\boldsymbol{r}}$ for a closed curve $C$, explain that claim.

**My attempt** (more thoughts)

f being differentiable is a way of saying it is continuous (differentiability implies continuity), while I can't formally state continuity in multiple dimensions, the definition of partial derivative is enough to tell me a proof wouldn't be difficult and the idea is largely trivial.

Now consider n=2, a surface, a continuous surface, to get from a height *a* to a height *b* is a conservative field because the difference between "the uppy bits" and "the downy bits" is constant no matter how you go from *a* to *b*, I should say perhaps "the amount of upness is constant" but that's equally bad. I don't like using words like uppy.

This is not a real analysis question, it is a calculus question, so I need not work with definitions (I need not formally state the above basically)

I'm not quite sure where to go from here. I am shocked that differentiability is sufficient for a conservative field (sufficient is all the question asks, it is not nessasary because of things like the field around an electric point charge, that is (using the same thoughts) conservative, hence electrical potential, although it does say any *differentiable* path.... hmmm)

I'm quite comfortable with the dot product and the idea of a scalar field (in this case) I'm just not sure how I'd go about proving it.

If anyone wants to bring Analysis into this I'd love that, unfortunately I am away from my books currently and it's been a while.

PS: How do I underline? Thanks

Comment: You're looking for \nabla (that is, $\nabla$).  You also want \cdot (that is, $\cdot$) for dot products.  What is it you need to underline?

Comment: @Muphrid any vectors in there, I used bold because I wasn't sure what it was.

Comment: Please note that the continuous-differentiability of $f$ is enough for $\nabla f$ to be conservative. It is false that any continuously-differentiable vector field is conservative.

Comment: @JonathanY. please put some of that into an answer! I am still quite blank sadly.

Comment: @Muphrid I'm sorry for being rude! Thanks for answering by the way, I just ignored the rest of the comment and answered the underline part, I am very grateful.

Comment: @JonathanY. while there has been an answer, I'd still love you to elaborate.

Comment: The point I wanted to emphasize is that exactness (the property of a field being conservative) isn't a mere result of differentiability (that *would* be exceedingly odd), but the fact that we're considering a field ($\nabla f$) that is already the 'derivative' of another field, in some sense. It turns out that such 'derivatives'--in the proper sense--are very well behaving, as the generalized Stokes theorem demonstrates.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $r: [a,b] \rightarrow C_{pq}$, with $r(a)=p$ and $r(b)=q$.

We have $\nabla f(r(t))\cdot r'(t)= D_t f(r(t))$. So, 
$$
\int_{C_{pq}} \nabla f ds=\int_a^b \nabla f(r(t))\cdot r'(t) dt = \int_a^b D_t f(r(t)) dt=f(r(b))-f(r(a))=f(q)-f(p)
$$

Comment: I should have seen that (honest) thanks, lovely and short.

Comment: I'll add that we're assuming $r$ is $C^1$, but the result is easily generalized to the case that it fails to be so at a finite number of points.